# Drush script to save multiple nodes of different types

Tags: 8, drush

I wrote a function that updates fields of an "Intervention" content type and saves it, then saves the "Request" node that contains it, and then saves the "Dossier" node that contains that request.

Running that code in a Devel PHP form work fine.

Now I'm trying to convert that function into a drush script that I could schedule to run everyday. But running that script gives me a couple of errors that I don't understand.

In Renderer.php line 243:

> [LogicException]
> Render context is empty, because render() was called outside of a renderRoot() or renderPlain() call. Use renderPla
> in()/renderRoot() or #lazy_builder/#pre_render instead.

In SqlContentEntityStorage.php line 846:

> [Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException]
> Render context is empty, because render() was called outside of a renderRoot() or renderPlain() call. Use renderPla
> in()/renderRoot() or #lazy_builder/#pre_render instead.

Looking at the stack trace, it looks like a save() call on an entity is triggering these errors ... does anybody know what needs to be done to correct them?

Thank you!

Function code ... comments are in french, sorry

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type', 'intervention')
->condition('field_type_intervention', '318')
->sort('changed', 'ASC');

$nids = $query->execute();
$node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
$nodes = $node_storage->loadMultiple($nids);
$i = 0;

// pour tous ces hébergements
foreach ($nodes as $n) {
  echo $n->title->value . "<br>";

  $dateDebutVal = $n->field_date_debut_intervention_1->value;
  $dateFinVal = $n->field_date_fin_intervention_1->value;

  $nbChambres = $n->field_nombre_chambres->value;
  $tarifNuitee = $n->field_tarif_nuitee->value;

  echo  'dateDebut='.$dateDebutVal. '<br>';
  echo  'dateFin='.$dateFinVal. '<br>';
  $dateDebut = strtotime($dateDebutVal);

  if ($dateFinVal != "") {
    $dateFin = strtotime($dateFinVal);
  }
  else {
    $dateFin = time();
  }

  $datediff = $dateFin - $dateDebut;
  $nbJours = floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

  if ($nbJours == 0) {
    $nbJours++;
  }

  echo 'nbJours = '.$nbJours. '<br>';
  $n->set('field_nombre_nuitee', $nbJours);

  // si le nombre de chambre et le tarif nuitée sont settés, calculer le montant estimé
  if ($nbChambres != "" && $tarifNuitee != "") {
    echo 'estimation = '.number_format($tarifNuitee * $nbChambres * $nbJours, 2, '.', ''). '<br>';
    $n->set('field_cout_estime', number_format($tarifNuitee * $nbChambres * $nbJours, 2, '.', ''));
  }

  // sauvegarder l'hébergement
  $n->save();

  // aller chercher la requête de cet hébergement et la sauvegarder
  $queryRequete = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'requete')
    ->condition('field_intervention_service', $n->id())
    ->sort('changed', 'ASC');

  $nidsRequete = $queryRequete->execute();
  $requetes = $node_storage->loadMultiple($nidsRequete);

  foreach ($requetes as $r) {
    echo $r->title->value . '<br>';
    $r->save();

    $queryDossier = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('type', 'dossier')
      ->condition('field_requete_menage', $r->id())
      ->sort('changed', 'ASC');

    $nidsDossier = $queryDossier->execute();
    $dossiers = $node_storage->loadMultiple($nidsDossier);

    foreach ($dossiers as $d) {
      echo $d->title->value . '<br>';
      $d->save();
    }
  }

  // aller chercher le dossier lié à cette requête et le sauvegarder
  $i++;
}

echo 'i = '.$i. '<br>';
```

Stack trace for LogicException

> Exception trace:
> at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php:243
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer.php:200
> Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\modules\contrib\serial\src\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\SerialDefaultFormatter.php:33
> Drupal\serial\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\SerialDefaultFormatter->viewElements() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase.php:89
> Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase->view() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay.php:263
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay->buildMultiple() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay.php:221
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay->build() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder.php:472
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->viewField() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList.php:243
> Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList->view() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\modules\contrib\token\token.tokens.inc:1630
> field_tokens() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler.php:403
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Utility\Token.php:304
> Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->generate() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\modules\contrib\token\token.tokens.inc:937
> token_tokens() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler.php:403
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Utility\Token.php:304
> Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->generate() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Utility\Token.php:196
> Drupal\Core\Utility\Token->replace() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\modules\contrib\auto_entitylabel\src\AutoEntityLabelManager.php:264
> Drupal\auto_entitylabel\AutoEntityLabelManager->generateLabel() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\modules\contrib\auto_entitylabel\src\AutoEntityLabelManager.php:145
> Drupal\auto_entitylabel\AutoEntityLabelManager->setLabel() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\modules\contrib\auto_entitylabel\auto_entitylabel.module:170
> auto_entitylabel_entity_presave() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler.php:403
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invokeAll() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase.php:206
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->invokeHook() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase.php:843
> Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->invokeHook() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase.php:500
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->doPreSave() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase.php:700
> Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doPreSave() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase.php:454
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage.php:837
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase.php:395
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->save() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\modules\custom\gosr_mod\script_update_nb_nuitees.php:75
> include() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\src\Commands\core\PhpCommands.php:111
> Drush\Commands\core\PhpCommands->script() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\CommandProcessor.php:257
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\CommandProcessor.php:212
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\CommandProcessor.php:176
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\AnnotatedCommand.php:302
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:255
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:1005
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:255
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:148
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\src\Runtime\Runtime.php:118
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\src\Runtime\Runtime.php:49
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php:72
> require() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\drush:4

Stack trace for EntityStorageException

> Exception trace:
> at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage.php:846
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase.php:395
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityBase->save() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\modules\custom\gosr_mod\script_update_nb_nuitees.php:75
> include() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\src\Commands\core\PhpCommands.php:111
> Drush\Commands\core\PhpCommands->script() at n/a:n/a
> call_user_func_array() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\CommandProcessor.php:257
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->runCommandCallback() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\CommandProcessor.php:212
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->validateRunAndAlter() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\CommandProcessor.php:176
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\CommandProcessor->process() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\consolidation\annotated-command\src\AnnotatedCommand.php:302
> Consolidation\AnnotatedCommand\AnnotatedCommand->execute() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php:255
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:1005
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:255
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:148
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\src\Runtime\Runtime.php:118
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\src\Runtime\Runtime.php:49
> Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php:72
> require() at C:\xampp\htdocs\gosr\vendor\drush\drush\drush:4

Comment: Looks like you have an old version of the Serial Field module - the `render` call is fixed in the current alpha release

Comment: Yep! That solved it. Thank you very much!